# Init lazy property with dynamic property

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection, lazy-evaluation

I would like init a lazy property dynamically with reflection.

I loop on my object properties and I want to create a lazy loading of this property like this :

```
Lazy<propertyInfo.propertyType> = new lazy<propertyInfo.propertyType>(() => methodInfo.invoke)
```

Lazy doesn't allow this.

Is there a way to do this with reflection ? (maybe activator.createinstance)

Comment: Could you show the definition of the class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Lazy<object> lazyType = new Lazy<object>(() => {
    return Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.propertyType);
});

lazyType.Value;
```

when u access the Value property the Lazy object will call the Func and then return an instance of your property type.

hope it helps